# Web scraping Reed.co.uk returns no results

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to build a webscraper for Reed.co.uk to pull a list of jobs. However, when I run the code it returns no results. Everything is working and I get no errors. It just doesn't return any results. What am I doing wrong? I used the same method for Indeed and it works perfectly each time. I have inspected the website and I have tried a number of different titles for the divs section

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    
#get URL
    def extract():
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
        url = 'https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/warehouse-operative-jobs-in-portsmouth'
        r = requests.get(url, headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        return soup
#extract required company data from adverts and append to joblist    
    def transform(soup):
        divs = soup.find_all('article', class_ = 'job-result   ')
        for item in divs:
            title = item.find('h3', class_ = 'title')
            company = item.find('div', class_ = 'posted-by')
            try:
                salary = item.find('div', class_ = 'metadata')
            except:
                salary = ''
            summary = item.find('div', class_ = 'description')
            
            job = {
                'Title' : title,
                'Company' : company,
                'Salary' : salary,
                'Summary' : summary
                }
            joblist.append(job)
        return
    
          
                
    joblist = []
    
    
    
    for i in range(0,40,10):
        print(f'Getting page,{i}')
        c = extract()
        transform(c)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(joblist)
    
    df.to_csv('jobs.csv')
```

'''

Comment: im not used to bs4, but your ```return``` is missing, what it should return, maybe change to ```return job```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to get information from that page into pandas DataFrame:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/warehouse-operative-jobs-in-portsmouth?pageno={}"

all_data = []

for page in range(1, 3):
    print("Getting page {}".format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).content, "html.parser")

    for job in soup.select("#server-results article"):
        title = job.h3.get_text(strip=True)
        posted_by = job.select_one(".posted-by").a.get_text(strip=True)
        salary = job.select_one(".salary")
        salary = salary.get_text(strip=True) if salary else ""
        description = job.select_one(".description").p.get_text(strip=True)

        all_data.append((title, posted_by, salary, description))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Title", "Company", "Salary", "Summary"])
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: That is perfect thank you for your help. Was there a particular reason it was not assigning things? Looks like I was looking at the wrong part?